# turn rows into column for every nth row

Tags: linux, unix, rows, multiple-columns

I have an out.txt that I would like to read into columns instead of rows. I would like to turn rows 1-5 into a column, 6-10 into a column, ect.  Can anyone point me into the right direction?

```
diff -r ./playground2/GN_GLENDALE_BILLS_130911_113722.txt ./playground/GN_GLENDALE_BILLS_130911_113722.txt
22c22
< N4*MCDONALDS*KY*40512~^M
---
> N4*LEXINGTON*KY*40512~^M
diff -r ./playground2/GN_GLENDALE_BILLS_130911_113723.txt ./playground/GN_GLENDALE_BILLS_130911_113723.txt
22c22
< N4*MCDONALDS*KY*40512~^M
---
> N4*LEXINGTON*KY*40512~^M
diff -r ./playground2/GN_GLENDALE_BILLS_130911_113725.txt ./playground/GN_GLENDALE_BILLS_130911_113725.txt
22c22
< N4*MCDONALDS*KY*40512~^M
---
> N4*LEXINGTON*KY*40512~^M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file has a number of lines evenly divisible by 5 (or that any remainder lines are to be ignored), this should work just fine:

```
filein=out.txt
fid=15                        #file identifier
nlines=`cat $filein | wc -l`  #count number of lines in file
eval "exec $fid<$filein"
for cnt in $(seq 1 $((nlines/5))); do
   read <&$fid line1
   read <&$fid line2
   read <&$fid line3
   read <&$fid line4
   read <&$fid line5
   echo $line1 $line2 $line3 $line4 $line5
done
eval "exec $fid<&-"
```

Basically, it just does a for loop for 1/5th the number of lines in the file, reading 5 lines at a time and spitting them all out at once.